# Vuex method mapGetters can't fetch values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

I have one modal for create user. There I need to call API and I am calling it through vuex store method i.e `mapGetters`. However it's not working. Can anyone tell me whats missing here?

`create-user` file.

```
import {mapGetters} from "vuex"

computed: {
    ...mapGetters("Entities", ["getEntities"]),
}
```

`entities` file:

```
const state = () => ({
  entities: []
})
const getters = {
  getEntities: (state) => state.entities
}
const mutations = {
  setEntities(state, entities) {
    state.entities = [...entities]
  }
}

const actions = {
  async fetchEntities({commit}) {
    return await axios.get('/entity')
      .then((resp) => {
          commit("setEntities", resp)             
          return true
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong here,  your ```actions```, ```fetchEntities``` makes the get request but ```state.entites``` is not begin updated. I think you need a to call ```setEntities``` where you're returning resp in actions. You can take a look at th example here: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/vuex-actions

Comment: any errors in the browser console? can you show how you're attempting to do what "doesn't work" perhaps you're "doing it wrong"

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the response. But i'm updating setEntities value, i forgot to add that line in question code. its : commit("setEntities", resp)

Comment: No errors were found in the browser console @Bravo. But I found the solution and mentioned as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, I wasn't calling fetchEntities mapAction in my vue file on created() method. fetchEntities fetch the data and then put it to the mapGetters.

Thanks for your support and for giving valuable time to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call namespaced modules, you have to namespace your modules:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing